# Rails Nesting paths, not resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an `Author` model with `name` as a field - it `has_many` Articles.

I also have an `Article` model with `name` and `description` as fields - it `belongs_to` Author and `has_many` Comments.

Finally, I have a `Comment` model, with `comment_text` and `article_id` as fields - it `belongs_to` Article,

I am looking for nesting paths i. e. ,(authors/:id/comments)
How do I nest paths, but not resources?

To clarify, I don't want to use `author_id` in the Comment model, but when I visit authors/:id/comments, I should be able to see all articles associated with author and comment on them.

Comment: Thank you very much Zoran, for re-framing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Author**

```
has_many :articles
has_many :comments, :through => :articles (This line will give you comments for the author)
```

**Article**

```
belongs_to :author (means it has author_id as a field)
has_many :comments
```

**Comment**

```
belongs_to :article
```

If the above structure is there in your model, then you can do:

```
@author = Author.where(:id => some_id)
@comments = @author.comments
```

You don't need to have **author_id** in Comment table.

Comment: Thank you very much Abhi, is there a way wherein I can get 'some_id' from the url: authors/:some_id/comments.

Comment: I got it, nesting resources with has_many through does the magic.

Comment: @ManjunathP Cool...if this answer was helpful, accept it as correct answer, so that it may help others in future